# JavaScript onclick event is not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

A simple JavaScript onclick event is not working but I don't understand why, here is the code:

```
<button onclick="removeLol()">remove style</button>

function removeLol() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

and here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/YNQg6/1/

Comment: Changing the fiddle to use "No wrap" fixes it. But that solution may not be what you need in the real page.

Comment: Tip: Check the console for errors.

Comment: @funkybro No, that's not right. You need parentheses to call a function.

Answer (score 4):

That's only because of the way how jsfiddle inserts the javascript.

Jsfiddle wraps your code into a function which limits the scope and protects the global namespace:

```
window.onload=function(){
  function removeLol() {
    alert("hello");
    element.className = element.className.replace(" lol ", "");
  }
}
```

If you tell jsfiddle to inject the code into the `document body` it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/YNQg6/13/

Or you could turn your "local" function in a global one:

```
window.removeLol = removeLol;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand I haven't tested the code on localhost because I have been playing on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine (just tried it on my server). Check your console for other errors that may be causing the script to not run